file creation time system call in linux/gcc
As I know, stat/fstat system call tell us only 3 times about a file

Time of last access  (st_atim field)
Time of last modification (st_mtim field)
Time of last status change (st_ctim)

and when I run stat filename command in bash, I can get creation time as Birth of the file. My question is, how can I get creation time in gcc by some system calls?

I don't think this is a gcc thing, but instead libc; I've changed the tags accordingly.

Most filesystems don't store file creation date, so this information isn't available in the general case.

Use statx.
From man 2 statx:

SYNOPSIS
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <fcntl.h>           /* Definition of AT_* constants */
   int statx(int dirfd, const char *pathname, int flags,
             unsigned int mask, struct statx *statxbuf);

DESCRIPTION
This  function returns information about a file, storing it in the buffer pointed to by statxbuf.  The returned buffer is a structure
of the fol‐
lowing type:
       struct statx {
           __u32 stx_mask;        /* Mask of bits indicating
                                     filled fields */
           __u32 stx_blksize;     /* Block size for filesystem I/O */
           __u64 stx_attributes;  /* Extra file attribute indicators */
           __u32 stx_nlink;       /* Number of hard links */
           __u32 stx_uid;         /* User ID of owner */
           __u32 stx_gid;         /* Group ID of owner */
           __u16 stx_mode;        /* File type and mode */
           __u64 stx_ino;         /* Inode number */
           __u64 stx_size;        /* Total size in bytes */
           __u64 stx_blocks;      /* Number of 512B blocks allocated */
           __u64 stx_attributes_mask;
                                  /* Mask to show what's supported
                                     in stx_attributes */

           /* The following fields are file timestamps */
           struct statx_timestamp stx_atime;  /* Last access */
           struct statx_timestamp stx_btime;  /* Creation */
           struct statx_timestamp stx_ctime;  /* Last status change */
           struct statx_timestamp stx_mtime;  /* Last modification */


That shows a field for a creation file stamp, appropriately named stx_btime (status extended birth time, I guess).
Note that for Darwin (and presumably any BSD), stat() contains a field struct timespec st_birthtimespec already, and there is no statx().
